# Most pythonic way to get variable based on last element in generator?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_variable = None

    def func1(self):
        i = 1

        while i < 10:
            yield i * i
            self.some_variable = len(str((i * i)))
            i += 1

    def func2(self):
        *_, last = my_class.func1()
        print(self.some_variable)


my_class = MyClass()

my_class.func2()
```

As you can see, some_variable is the length of the last element in the generator. Basically, I was wondering, is this the most pythonic way of getting this variable? If not, how should this be done? I'm just wondering if this is how it should be done or if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Not sure your example is the best, you know what the last value of `i` will be in your generator so `some_variable` will just be equal to `len(str(9 * 9))` or `2`?

Comment: In this case, some_variable is known as well as i beforehand. However, in my actual code this is not the case.  I just wrote a simple example to center the focus on my question to make it easier to read.

Comment: What would the different ways of storing a last variable in a generator like this be? How would you do it? The above code works, but I'm just wondering if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Can your question be re-worded like "how can I completely consume a generator and store the last yielded value"? A generator may be infinite...

Comment: In which case, convert it to a list and get the last value via negative indexing

Comment: Yeah, well, I'm not exactly trying to store the last element of a generator, which would be i * i, but the variable that gets updated inside the generator, aka some_variable.

Comment: Do you mind posting the updated code?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest code is to simply use a `for` loop to consume the generator, doing nothing in the loop body. The loop variable will have the last value from the generator after the loop ends, which is exactly what you want.

```
for x in some_generator():
    pass

print(x) # print the last value yielded by the generator
```

This may be a little more efficient than other options because it discards all the values before the last one, rather than storing them in a list or some other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one pythonic way would be to yield both the element and the length:

```py
def func1():
    i = 1

    while i < 10:
        yield i * i, len(str((i * i)))
        i += 1

def func2():
    *_, (_, last_len) = func1()
    print(last_len)


func2()
```

or even to extract the calculation of the derived value to another function and call it after consuming the generator:

```py
def func1():
    i = 1

    while i < 10:
        yield i * i
        i += 1

def func2(i):
    return len(str(i))

def func3():
    *_, last = func1()
    print(func2(last))


func3()
```

I think that you have simplified your example too much to be able to find the solution that fits your real use case the best.